# How does Redis Cluster handle replication for sorted sets ZSET (and others)?

Tags: data-structures, redis, sortedset

Redis Cluster supports sorted sets. How is the replication login implemented if used with a replication factor > 1? Is the master node forwarding all actions applied against the sorted set to the replica nodes or is there some other mechanism (e.g. copying the whole set over the wire everytime something changes)?

Subquestions: how reliable is this replication? How does it scales with both frequently accessed and huge sorted sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis' replication is operation-based, meaning that the slaves get the stream of write commands from the master. The replication mechanism isn't related to the clustering functionality and works the same whether used in a cluster or by a standalone Redis server.

The replication is extremely reliable but note that it is asynchronous.